# regexp for at commands

Tags: tcl, expect, at-command

I am using tcl and expect to send and read AT commands from a phone (I would like to send sms using at commands). I am sending AT commands through expect as follows:

```
exp_send "AT\r"
expect {
        -re "(.*)OK"  {puts "Connected"}
}
```

Now I am trying to query the modes supported by phone

```
exp_send "AT+CMGF=?\r"
expect {
       -re "AT(.*)"  {puts "$expect_out(1,string)"}
       "timeout"     {puts "Timeout occured"}
}
```

The above expression I used is giving out the output as

```
+CMGF=?

+CMGF:(0-1)

OK.
```

I would like to read the output only which is:

```
+CMGF:(0-1)

OK.
```

Can anyone help me with a proper regexp that can be used to get the desired output?
Thanks.

Comment: `expect_out(1,string)` is supposed to give the 1st sub match given by us in `regexp`. Can you post the manual command execution of AT device ? Also, try a run with `exp_internal 1` and check for the debug information

Answer (score 0):

You need a more complex RE:

```
expect {
    -re {AT\+CGMF:([^\n\r]+)} {
        puts "$expect_out(1,string)"
        exp_continue
    }
    OK { puts "done" }
    timeout { puts "timed out" }
}
```